# Consulta procedimiento almacenado pasando lista

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net, .net

Estoy lanzando desde un servicio en .NET una consulta a SQL Server para que me devuelva los detalles de una tabla pasandole una lista de identificadores. 
He llegado a una soluciona "muy sucia" a mi ver... aunque por lo visto mientras funcione sirve. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma mas elegante y sin que sea tan feo hacerlo.

C#

```
public GetAccountsResponseDto GetAccounts(GetAccountsRequest request)
    {
        List<SqlParameter> parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
        string listSql = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            foreach (string numero in request.Numeros)
            {
                listSql += "'" + numero.ToString() + "',";
            }

            parameters.Add(_sql.CreateParameter("@numeros", listSql.Substring(0, listSql.Length - 1), System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar));
            var table = _sql.GetDataTable("sp_Select_AccountsBalance", System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters.ToArray());

            return new GetAccountsResponseDto()
            {
                Results = MapperHelper<Balance>.Map(table).ToList()
            };

        }
        catch (DbException ex)
        {
            //TODO AUDIT                
        }
        return null;

    }
```

SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Select_AccountsBalance]
@numeros varchar(max) = null,
@CONSULTA as nvarchar(max) = null
AS
BEGIN   
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET @CONSULTA = 'SELECT InstanceId,Numero,Saldo,Disponible,Nombre as 
Tipo,Fecha,EsCredito,RiesgoAsignado,SaldoRetenido 
    FROM Cuenta JOIN TipoCuenta ON Cuenta.TipoCuenta = TipoCuenta.Id
    WHERE Numero IN (' + @numeros + ') order by Numero'
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL  @CONSULTA
END
```

Answer (score 4):

Si necesitas pasar una lista puedes definir el parametro como `Table-Valued Parameters`

[Parámetros con valores de tabla](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Entonces pasas el array como si fuera una tabla, es mas en la query del procedure puedes usar el `INNER JOIN` que es mejor al `IN` que estas implementando

Creas un tipo

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CuentaTableType AS TABLE  
    ( Numero int)
```

Luego el procedure usarias

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Select_AccountsBalance]
    @tvpCuentaNumero dbo.CuentaTableType READONLY
AS
BEGIN   

    SELECT InstanceId,Numero,Saldo,
            Disponible,Nombre as Tipo,
            Fecha,EsCredito,
            RiesgoAsignado,SaldoRetenido 
        FROM Cuenta C
        INNER JOIN TipoCuenta TC ON C.TipoCuenta = TC.Id
        INNER JOIN @tvpCuentaNumero CN ON CN.Numero = C.Numero

END
```

En el codigo .net quedaria

```
public GetAccountsResponseDto GetAccounts(GetAccountsRequest request)
{
    DataTable dtParam = new DataTable();
    dtParam.Columns.Add("Numero", typeof(int));

    foreach (string numero in request.Numeros)
    {
        var row = dt.NewRow();
        row["Numero"] = Convert.ToInt32(numero);
        dtParam.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Select_AccountsBalance", connection);  
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
    SqlParameter tvpParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpCuentaNumero", dtParam);  
    tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dtResult);

    return new GetAccountsResponseDto()
    {
        Results = MapperHelper<Balance>.Map(dtResult).ToList()
    };

}
```

Fijate como se define el parametro con `SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured`

NUNCA defines un `try..catch` en el codigo vacio, es una pesima practica de programacion

Comment: Muchas gracias, he cambiado con todo lo que me has pasado y me has abierto un nuevo mundo!! Por cierto el try..catch estoy esperando a que me den permisos para grabar los problemas en una auditoria

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que considero de que la opción de Leandro es óptima, existe una alternativa que permite trabajar con cadenas delimitadas. Esta opción, a diferencia de lo que habías realizado, no es vulnerable a inyección de SQL. Para utilizarla, sólo necesitamos crear una función que divida una cadena delimitada en multiples valores. Esta ha sido probada como una de las más rápidas en T-SQL con la limitante de que sólo soporta hasta 8000 caracteres. Fue creada por MVP Jeff Moden y modificada por Eirikur Eirikson.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD](
--===== Definir parámetros
    @pString VARCHAR(8000), 
    @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
)  
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS  
 RETURN  
--===== Tabla de números (tally table) generada al vuelo con hasta 10,000 números 
     -- suficiente para soportar VARCHAR(8000)  
 WITH E1(N) AS (  
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL   
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1  
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 filas  
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 filas
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 filas max  
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== Provee una base de zero y limita el número de filas desdeel inicio
                     -- para obtener un mejor rendimiento y prevenir valores extras
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL  
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4  
                ),  
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== Regresa N+1 (posición de inicio de cada elemento una vez por delimitador)
                 SELECT t.N+1  
                   FROM cteTally t  
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0)   
                )  
--===== Hacer la división de valores. El combo ISNULL/NULLIF maneja la longitud para el elemento final cuando no se encuentra un delimitador
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),  
        Item = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF((LEAD(s.N1,1,1) OVER (ORDER BY s.N1) - 1),0)-s.N1,8000))  
   FROM cteStart s  
;
```

Una vez teniendo esta función, el procedimiento quedaría así

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Select_AccountsBalance](
    @numeros varchar(8000) 
)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT InstanceId,
        Numero,
        Saldo,
        Disponible,
        Nombre as Tipo,
        Fecha,
        EsCredito,
        RiesgoAsignado,
        SaldoRetenido 
FROM Cuenta 
JOIN TipoCuenta ON Cuenta.TipoCuenta = TipoCuenta.Id
WHERE Numero IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@numeros, ',')) 
ORDER BY Numero;
```

Evita utilizar el prefijo sp_ para procedimientos almacenados. SP significa "special" y está reservado para objetos del sistema, no solo para procedimientos almacenados.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 formas estándar que he visto que utilizan varias empresas, la mas antigua y común es usar un `XML(MSSQLServer > 2005)` te dejo un ejemplo:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Produccion].[TestXML] 
    @Detalle XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @i INT;
    DECLARE @TableDetalle TABLE(
        Item SMALLINT IDENTITY,
        Galpon CHAR(2),
        ProduccionTipo TINYINT,
        Edad INT,
        Unidades INT
    )

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @i OUTPUT, @Detalle
    INSERT INTO @TableDetalle(
        Galpon,
        ProduccionTipo,
        Edad,
        Unidades
    )
    SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@i, N'/DocumentElement/Detalle')
    WITH (
        Galpon CHAR(2), 
        ProduccionTipo TINYINT,
        Edad INT,
        Unidades INT
    ) EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @i;

 END
```

y el snipper de c#

```
public static bool Grabar(List<testItem> ObjDetalleIn, string cadenaConexion)
        {
            int Respuesta = 0;
            using (ModeloProduccionAves objModelo = new ModeloProduccionAves(cadenaConexion))
            {
                XElement xmlElementMainClasificacion = new XElement("DocumentElement");
                foreach (testItem itemDetalle in ObjDetalleIn)
                    xmlElementMainClasificacion.Add(new XElement("Detalle",
                        new XAttribute("Galpon", itemDetalle.Galpon),
                        new XAttribute("ProduccionTipo", itemDetalle.ProduccionTipo),
                        new XAttribute("Edad", 0),
                        new XAttribute("Unidades", itemDetalle.Unidades)));

                SqlParameter objDetalleClasificacion = new SqlParameter("@Detalle", xmlElementMainClasificacion.ToString());
                objDetalleClasificacion.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Xml;

                object[] parametros = new object[] {
                    objDetalleClasificacion
                };
                Respuesta = objModelo.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.Data.Entity.TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction, "Produccion.TestXML @Detalle", parametros);
            }
            return Math.Abs(Respuesta) > 0;
        }
```

El otro método es para motores de `MSSQLServer > 2016` es usando [JSON](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

No tengo el método pero es muy parecido al que tienes pero se utiliza la librería [Newton.JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Select_AccountsBalance]
@numeros varchar(max) = null,
@CONSULTA as nvarchar(max) = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT InstanceId,Numero,Saldo,Disponible,Nombre as 
           Tipo,Fecha,EsCredito,RiesgoAsignado,SaldoRetenido 
    FROM Cuenta JOIN TipoCuenta ON Cuenta.TipoCuenta = TipoCuenta.Id
    WHERE Numero IN (SELECT CAST(value as INT ) 
                    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@numeros, ',')) 
    order by Numero;
END
```